# What is the size of Cache Directory in iPhone and iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I am currently storing around 58 MB of files needed by my app in Library/Cache directory of the app.

I have some users who complain that they are not able to see these files. I suspect this may be because cache directory gets purged by OS in Low Space conditions.

So, I would like to know the size of Cache directory so that I can plan for storing my files.

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean "they are not able to see these files", are they trying to see it via itunes?

Comment: If your app is relying on those files, don't put them into the cache directory :)

Comment: I think there is no limitation to store the data in Cache directory, because our app is catalog type it has more than 20 catalogs with 300dpi jpeg image with size of 229 MB each and 10 video total size is 1GB this are all downloaded from server and stored in subfolder of cache directory of our app it works fine its in app store

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava, users are not able to see these files means they can't access these files anymore.

Comment: @deanWombourne, Apple did not allow us to put these files in Documents directory because of new data storage guidelines for iOS 5. Hence we had to put it in Cache directory.

Comment: If they are _required_ then they can go into the documents folder. If they can be _recreated_ then they should go into the cache folder. sounds like these files are required :)

Comment: Actually these are required and can be recreated by the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that size is undefined and you can store content until you fill all disk space. But there is one note for Cache directory -

> On iOS 5.0 and later, the system may delete the Caches directory on
>   rare occasions when the system is very low on disk space. This will
>   never occur while an app is running. However, you should be aware that
>   iTunes restore is not necessarily the only condition under which the
>   Caches directory can be erased.

See [The Library Directory Stores App-Specific Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1)